# Forwarding signals to child processes created with Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, signals, popen

I have a Python program that is a thin wrapper around arbitrary (i.e. non-Python) programs. The wrapper uses [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to start the wrapped programs.

Sometimes, however, the wrapped programs ignore signals such as `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`. The result is, when the wrapper program is running such a program and receives a CTRL-C, only the wrapper is killed but the wrapped program continues to run.

Is it possible to let the wrapper catch any signal and just "forward" it to the wrapped program?

I could use something more drastic as [atexit.register](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) in the wrapper to just kill the child process whenever the wrapper is terminating, but I figure, forwarding the signals might be cleaner?

Comment: Have you looked at [Popen.send_signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
import subprocess
import signal

wrapped_proc = subprocess.Popen(...)

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    wrapped_proc.send_signal(signum)
    # anything else

signal.signal(signal_handler, signal.SIGINT)
```

Link to [signal documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal)